# Complicated integral, where $\int\coth(x)dx$ is somehow written in terms of $\int |x|e^{ix}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

In Gardiner's Quantum Noise the following integral equality is used (eq 3.3.10, 3.3.14):
$$\int_0^{\infty}d\omega \omega\mathrm{coth}\left(\frac{a\omega}{2}\right)\cos(\omega(t-t'))=\int_0^{\infty}d\omega \left[\omega\mathrm{coth}\left(a\omega\right)-\omega\right]\cos(\omega(t-t'))$$
$$+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega|\omega|e^{i\omega(t-t')}$$
The aim of this is to write the divergent integral on the left as the sum of convergent and divergent parts.

I have been trying to see where this comes from. So far I have noted that:
$$\coth(x)=\coth(2x)+\frac{2}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}$$
which lets me write:
$$=\int_0^\infty d\omega\left[\omega\coth(a\omega)-\omega\right]\cos(\omega(t-t'))+\int_0^{\infty}d\omega\omega\cos(\omega(t-t'))$$
$$+\int_0^{\infty}d\omega\frac{2\omega}{e^{a\omega}-e^{-a\omega}}\cos(\omega(t-t'))$$
Furthermore we have:
$$\int_0^{\infty}d\omega\omega\cos(\omega(t-t'))=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega|\omega|\cos(\omega(t-t'))$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}d\omega\frac{2\omega}{e^{a\omega}-e^{-a\omega}}\cos(\omega(t-t'))=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\frac{2\omega}{e^{a\omega}-e^{-a\omega}}\cos(\omega(t-t'))$$
From here though I can't see how to proceed, and am especially confused as to where the complex exponential could possibly have come from. Any ideas at all would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega|\omega|\cos(\omega(t-t'))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega|\omega|e^{i\omega(t-t')}
\end{align}

because  $i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega|\omega|sin(\omega(t-t'))=0$,
 we integrate an odd function over an even interval.

Edit:
I don't see why this second integral should vanish mathematically. 
Is this maybe one of the standard physics arguments that one just absorbs some finite value in the redefinition of a physical quantity?

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful. I didn't see an argument of that type made in the text but maybe it was done implicitly, I will give it another look.